# OpenCL Work-Items and Work-Groups

Tags: opencl

I am running a kernel on GPU using an NDRange with
global size: 32
local size: 16
Dimensions: 1

Now when I look at the results from the buffer I can see the values coming from each work item. Now from work item 32 up to 512 the values are 0 so this makes me think that not all work-items are running.

I am getting the id of the work-item using get_global_id(0).

How can this be? If I run 512 work groups with 1 work-item each then it works fine. What am I missing?

Thanks Everyone

Comment: Are you from cuda? In there, people derived total threads from number of groups but here you derive groups from total threads. So you need just workitems? Then pass global size. Then altering local size changes that group size that decides how many groups can be in flight per compute unit. 512 global + 16 local = 32 groups then each compute unit better have less than 16 cores to minimize disefficiency.

Comment: Yeah I sort of come from CUDA. So in this case why are you saying that each compute unit better have less than 16 cores?

Comment: Opencl workitems scgeduling cant use all cores because of in flight Groups working on same lanes and Having ilp less. I mean amd gpu gets very slow with just 16 items per group

Comment: I would really like someone explaining me how this whole thing about group works. Because I always thought it was the opposite about local and global.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global size you specify during enqueueing must still be 512 - it's not the number of groups, but the total number of items.

Answer (score 2):

`get_global_id(0)` gives a workitem's own id. Think of it like this:

```
// gpu driver runs this
void gpu(int global_size)
{
    for(0 to global_size)
    {
        produce(
        {
           auto get_global_id=[](int dimension){ return loop_counter; };
           virtual void kernel( params ... )
           {
                 yourKernelCodeHere
           }
        }, toQueue);
    }
}

// compute units run this

while(fromQueue is not empty)
{
     consume(local_size_chunks, fromQueue);
}
```

Workitem is a unit of work/worker defined as a kernel.

Local size is number of workitems per group. A group's workitems share resources of 1 compute unit. 1 compute unit contains local memory, cache, alu and some more.

Global size is integer multiple of local size, so N number of groups can be run.

From CPU point of view, each workitem can be a thread or a fiber or a lane of a SIMD.

From GPU point of view, each workitem can be a list of commands streaming through an alu.

From CPU point of view, a workgroup(size=local) can be a vectorized C++ loop and even unrolled version of it using multiple threads.

From GPU point of view, a workgroup can be a clamped parallel command stream(similar to pentium's dual-issue but wider), you may choose not to use all cores of a compute unit, even only 1 could be used but its inefficient.

Comment: If that's true then why I don't get the other work-items results?!

Comment: You defined 16=local size, 32=global size, so only 2 groups are retrieved to compute unit(s). 512 workitems would need global size 512. Quickest compute units(with probably many cores) get 16 workitems to consume, then next quickest one gets the other 16, all finishes.

Comment: Yeah but 16x32 is 512 work items. And as you said each work item is a unit of work.

Comment: No its not 16x32, it is 32/16 groups. 2 groups. 2x16=32 workitems(the way you meant). You are saying to gpu: "there are 32 workitems but consume them in 16-wide chunks".

Comment: Ok then if I set for example 512x32. I get invalid command queue. What could that mean?

Comment: Global size=512, local size=32? Shouldn't give error.

Comment: Is there anything I should know about __private variables of work-items? Because during the execution after some iterations I get that error

Comment: Are you re-creating command queues, buffer objects and kernels before each iteration? Thats overkill(and leaks if its old non-c++ wrapper). Create once, use any times as you like. Even setting arguments of kernels is needed only once. Don't forget to destroy-release in the opposite order you create them, after flushing-finishing command queue.

Comment: What I do recreate is buffers because for each iteration I need different sizes of arrays. Should I just declare the largest I can? I mean the largest I need and then just use it?

Comment: That would be another question with necessary algorithm details in mind.

Comment: Ok now I create buffers just once and it works. I am interested about finding the optimum local size though.

Comment: Depends on algorithm, number of hardware resources per compute unit, per group, per workitem and also slightly to compiler optimizations.

Comment: Ok so now I am running a new algorithm, I have finally switched to C++ Wrappers. I create objects (buffers etc) only once and I have again the same problem... If I set a local size it doesn't work... Why does OpenCL make it so difficult? Could it be because I have this in the code? "if (tid == 0) return;"

Comment: Again, if global size is not exact multiple of local size then it must be something in algorithm and you should ask that in new question. What codes do you have in kernel string?